# How can I update rustc from within Codespaces

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, github-codespaces

I am trying to build an example "Marco Polo" game using `Rust` with GitHub's `Codespaces`. I am following an example from Week 1 of Coursera's "Data Engineering with Rust" course. However, the vesion
of `rustc` in my `codespaces` is no longer sufficient for the current version of `clap_builder`, which seems to be required. My `Cargo.toml` file is as follows:

```
[package]
name = "hello_marco"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
clap = {version="4.0.32", features=["derive"]}
```

which matches the one given in the lesson. But, when I run it, I get this error:

```
error: package `clap_derive v4.5.0` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.74 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.70.0
Either upgrade to rustc 1.74 or newer, or use
cargo update -p clap_derive@4.5.0 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `clap_derive` supporting rustc 1.70.0
```

I do not seem to be able to update my version of rustc:

```
@me ➜ /workspaces/MarcoPolo2/hello_marco (main) $ rustup update
info: no updatable toolchains installed
info: checking for self-update
info: downloading self-update
info: cleaning up downloads & tmp directories
@me ➜ /workspaces/MarcoPolo2/hello_marco (main) $ rustc --version
rustc 1.70.0 (90c541806 2023-05-31)
```

When I look at the Clap [ChangeLog](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) it appears as though v 4.3.24 is the first one to support my current rust compiler (assuming that this is what `msrv` [minimum supported rust version] means]). I was able (I believe) to successfully downgrade my version of clap by

```
@me ➜ /workspaces/MarcoPolo2/hello_marco (main) $ cargo update -p clap@4.5.2 --precise 4.3.24
```

But, I still want to know how can I force my `codespaces` environment to use the more recent `rustc`.